# Windows Forms Touch Screen App Not Picking Up Button Click

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, touch

I have written a .net application using vb which emulates a keyboard, each button (I've tried with both native windows form buttons and devexpress simple buttons) on the form when clicked appends its text property to a label control. This works absolutely find on 3 of the 4 touch screens I have, however, the fourth screen is very intermitant in whether it will collect the touch.

Windows seemingly has registered the touch but the application does not acknowledge it (again this happens randomly on 1 hardware vendors device - a seperate model from the same hardware vendor works fine).

To make matters more confusing for me, the windows keyboard and native windows applications seem to work without issue on the same device. All devices tested are running Windows 10 LSBT.

I've even gone to the point where I am registering several events to prove that they are being picked up, and comparing the touch results to those of a stylus being used in its place (which incidentally works perfectly with no issues).

I've had a look at all touch options in windows, again with no real success and after now spending the entire week on this have pretty much run out of ideas.

Any tips / suggestions / straws to clutch onto at this point would be gratefully recieved,

Thanks

Chris

Comment: do you need whole keyboard or just numpad?

Comment: It's the whole keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the end between myself and a colleague we both went down the route of capturing gestures and manipulating to suit our needs.